# bad_alloc error in helper function

Tags: c++

Disclaimer: I am working on homework, but this is something I wrote.

I am trying to run through a linked list backwards and print the elements forward. This snippit should print:

```
Chicago
ELSE
Boston
IF
2, Boston, Chicago
```

But the function ends up printing / throwing this:

```
Chicago
ELSE
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

I've looked at other bad_alloc problems, but nothing has seemed to work. If I change my function so that e is a vertex* it prints this:

```
Chicago
ELSE
�3�����`��=��=��=��3�����p4�0=�P=�P=�(4�����>�0>�0>�x5������=�>�>��5�����P6��6��6�86������>��>��>��6�����0�`=�p=�p=�87������?� @�P@�h7�����P<�p<�p<��;�����`@��@��@�8<����� ?�P?�`?�1Seattle1�9���(:���1Yakima1�9����:�{�-1,-1!�<���!��1�:���@;�G�95,-1!h8���!p<���1h8���9�X�,-1!h8���Qh8����8�j�H9�X�-1,-1,-11,-1,-1,-1,-1!9�j�!�9���1�:����:���11,-1Q�@�!����-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,185,-1,142,01,142,0142,0108����9�`�1����@;�G�,142,01�>���@;�G�42,0Q�8�G��:���;� �,-1,0,1420,1420,142a�5����9����:�{�;���@;���,-1��8����9����:�{�;���@;���1�:���@;� �,0,142Q&����1095,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,185,-1,142,0142,01�6
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I don't  see it and haven't for about an hour.

```
void Graph::printHelp(vertex e,int c){
    cout << e.name << endl;
    if(e.previous == NULL) {
    cout << "IF" << endl;
        cout << c << ", " << e.name << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "ELSE" << endl;
        printHelp(*e.previous,c+1);
        std::cout << ", " << e.name << endl;
    }   
}
```

EDIT: Here is the pattern for the vertex struct:

```
struct vertex{
    std::string name;
    bool visited;
    int distance;
    vertex *previous;
    int district;
    std::vector<adjVertex> adj;
};
```

EDIT2: Even more of my code this is part of a BF search:

```
for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
    vertices[i].visited=false;
    vertices[i].previous=NULL;
}
vector<vertex> next;
next.push_back(vertices[s]);
for(z=0;!vertices[e].visited;z++){
    for(j=0;j<next[z].adj.size();j++){
        if(!next[z].adj[j].v->visited){
            next[z].adj[j].v->visited = true;
            next[z].adj[j].v->previous = &next[z];
            next.push_back(*(next[z].adj[j].v));
        }
    }
}

cout << vertices[s].name << endl;

printHelp(vertices[e],0);
cout << endl;
```

And here us the add Vertex method that makes the vertices:

```
void Graph::addVertex(string n){
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++){
        if(vertices[i].name == n){
            found = true;
            cout<<vertices[i].name<<" found."<<endl;
        }
    }
    if(found == false){
        vertex v;
        v.name = n;
        vertices.push_back(v);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information. What is `e` and how does it get initialized?

Comment: Can you show where you are creating each `vertex` and setting the `previous` pointer?

Comment: You can't store `vertex` instances in a vector like that, because every time the vector reallocates its storage, the pointers in the `vertex` need to be adjusted. Why do you have a `previous` pointer at all in there?

Comment: Wow my teacher has got us doing this quite wrong then.